# Google spreadsheet o,oo is not zero

Tags: google-sheets

I have a calculation which has as result  0,00     (0.00 in US notation)I test 
When i test this cell with this formula

=A1=0   the result if false

[image]

Probably it's a rounding issue. Is there a way to calculate with the result the screen shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try '=round(A1,2) = 0'

The result on screen is formatting that you apply to the cell